# How to display a BoxView passing parameters of type Double?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I've created a Xamarin.Forms project with both a XAML layout and a C# layout

On my Xaml ContentPage I did a Boxview inside my StackLayout like so

```
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     WidthRequest="100">
                <BoxView.Color>
                    <Color x:FactoryMethod="FromRgb">
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:Int32>0</x:Int32>
                            <x:Int32>0</x:Int32>
                            <x:Int32>255</x:Int32>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </Color>
                </BoxView.Color>
            </BoxView>
        <StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

```
    this.Content = new ScrollView {
        Content = new StackLayout {
        Children = {
            new BoxView{
                            Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255), 
                            HeightRequest = 100, 
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, 
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, 
                            WidthRequest = 100
                            }
                    }
            };
    }
```

on both pages I get the correct result of a box colored in blue

I've having trouble replicating the following in C# using Double type parameters

```
<Color x:FactoryMethod="FromRgb">
    <x:Arguments>
        <x:Double>1</x:Double>
        <x:Double>0</x:Double>
        <x:Double>0</x:Double>
    </x:Arguments>
</Color>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [Color.FromRgb Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.color.fromrgb?view=xamarin-forms) article, we can see that there are two method that having int and double parameter.

So if you use Double type parameter, you can also need to use Double type parameter in C#.

```
  this.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
        new BoxView{
                        Color = Color.FromRgb((double)1,(double)0, (double)0),
 HeightRequest = 100,
 HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
 VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, WidthRequest = 100
                            }
                    }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor; `public Color (double r, double g, double b);`

```
var myColor = new Color(r,g,b);
```